# Oracle SQL ERROR ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

thank you to whoever is reading this.

I made a trigger that is to be used in conjunction with a series of inserts I have made for a certain "Donations" table. The purpose of the trigger is to prevent any invalid entries into the table from showing up in the output of the select query after the entries have finished inserting. I will include a series of screenshots detailing the problem.

Here is the schema containing all the columns of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE donation (
    don_id              NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
    ,donor_first_name   VARCHAR2(16)
    ,donor_last_name    VARCHAR2(16)
    ,donation_date      DATE NOT NULL
    ,donation_amount    NUMBER(7,1) NOT NULL
    ,type_of_donation   VARCHAR2(12)
    ,address_id         NUMBER NOT NULL
    ,volunteer_id       NUMBER NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT fk_don_add FOREIGN KEY ( address_id )
        REFERENCES address ( address_id )
    ,CONSTRAINT fk_don_vol FOREIGN KEY ( volunteer_id )
        REFERENCES volunteer ( volunteer_id )
    );
```

Here are the inserts. There are 60 entries in total, and a few of them are invalid (by containing empty entries in the name columns etc.). I cut down the insert command into two photos that show the beginning and end:

```
INSERT ALL 
        INTO donation VALUES(001, 'Michael', 'Travis', '2021-03-16', 20, 'Cash', 39854, 100)
        INTO donation VALUES(002, 'Mitaeo', 'Akkaboune', '2021-03-22', 40, 'Cash', 7021, 141)
        INTO donation VALUES(003, 'Paul', 'Friat', '2021-03-22', 20, 'Cash', 7232, 141)
        ...
        INTO donation VALUES(059, 'Sasha', 'Wernicke', '2021-01-30', 30, 'Cash', 18991, 247)
        INTO donation VALUES(060, 'Samantha', 'Weiner', '2021-02-26', 60, 'Cheque', 30695, 146)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

This is the trigger I created:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IgnoreFaultyDonors
    BEFORE INSERT ON donation
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO donation (don_id, donor_first_name, donor_last_name, 
        donation_date, donation_amount, type_of_donation, address_id, 
        volunteer_id)
            SELECT don_id, donor_first_name, donor_last_name, donation_date, 
                    donation_amount, type_of_donation, address_id, volunteer_id
            FROM donation
            WHERE donor_first_name IS NOT NULL 
            AND donor_last_name IS NOT NULL
            AND (type_of_donation = 'Cash' OR type_of_donation = 'Cheque');
    END;
    /
```

[And this is the error I keep getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLrGb.jpg)

So yeah. I am wondering if there is an easy way to change this trigger I have here so that I can run the insert statements and subsequent select query without having triggering these kinds of errors. The inserts work just fine when the trigger is not enabled, but I need the invalid entries in the table to be withheld in my final output. I looked up compound triggers as a lot of solutions I have read so far from searching online mentioned to use them, but I'm coming across so many varied examples that it's hard for me to form a starting strategy in using them.

Any constructive advice and hints are much appreciated. In the meantime, I am going to keep researching.

P.S. Sorry if the images aren't good in case you wanted to copy/paste and test my code. I wanted to implement my code directly in here but the Code Sample feature isn't working very well. This is only my second post here so I'm quite inexperienced with this site.

Comment: A row-level trigger on `donation` cannot query the `donation` table.  That's the reason for the error.  It isn't obvious to me what rule you are trying to implement but it doesn't make sense to have an `insert into donation` in a `before insert` trigger on `donation`.

Comment: The idea is that when this trigger is activated, the output of the donations table will only contain entries where the first and last name columns contain data strings as opposed to null values (or being empty). I also threw in a couple entries where the donation_type was set to strings other than "Cash" and "Cheque" and those entries are to be invalidated as well. Whether I use BEFORE or AFTER in the trigger, it results in the same error every time. I'm just not sure where to go from here.

Comment: None of those things should require a trigger.  It sounds like you want `not null` constraints on the first and last name columns and a `check` constraint on `donation_type` (or better yet, a `donation_type` lookup table and a check constraint).  Is there some reason that you're trying to use a trigger for this?

Comment: The reason is that this is part of a college class assignment and the prof requires that the data contains some invalid entries for evaluation purposes. I could make the name columns NOT NULL in the schema, but then I would have to figure out a different way that invalid entries can be introduced and handled in the system without any errors occurring. I figured that leaving the names null would be the easiest way to accomplish this. I could just create limit conditionals on the characters or something in the select queries but don't know if that will count.

Comment: What specifically do you mean "handled in the system without any errors occurring"?  When an `insert` violates a constraint, an error is thrown and the `insert` statement fails.  The way to write a trigger that prevents a row from being inserted would be to throw an error that causes the `insert` statement to fail.  Silently allowing an `insert` to complete without an error and to not insert a row would be a terrible, terrible thing architecturally.  You could technically do it by doing all your inserts into a view with an `instead of` trigger but you really, really wouldn't want to.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not articulating my issue well. I mean...running a series of inserts, inputting rows into a table, and then discretely ignoring any rows that have 'faulty' entries so they don't show up in my output. I could add a NOT NULL constraint to those columns in the schema like you said, but then that would be the problem. I would have to insert names into those entries and then they would no longer be "invalid" entries. So I guess what I'm wondering now is if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Comment: It is really not clear what do you want to achieve. If you need an invalid records in your table, then you *should* allow them to be inserted and your later code *should* deal with such invalid records and filter them out (or mark them as invalid or whatever logic you want). If you want to preserve your database from invalid records, then no need to reinvent the wheel: apply constraints on columns, they are very straightforward. And your app will also handle this invalid records just disallowing them to go in, but it is real world usage of constraints. Compound triggers here are misused

Comment: I'm sorry if I can't make what I want any clearer than I have already -- I am trying. So what the consensus seems to be so far is that either I create subsequent code where I delete the faulty entries, or I add more constraints to the schema and update the table so that the faulty entries aren't taken at all. There is no automatic process I can use to ignore faulty entries so they won't show up in a query output.

Comment: Normally, in an OLTP application, if you can define rules that constrain what makes a valid row, you'd define those as constraints on the table and it would be beneficial that invalid `insert` statements throw an error because that alerts the user that the value they were trying to save wasn't saved and lets them fix it.  In a data warehouse, you might take a different path and load all rows into an initial landing table before doing further validation and processing but you wouldn't delete rows that failed validation they just wouldn't get moved along the pipeline.

Comment: It is conceivable that you want to load invalid data and then have a view on top of the table that only presents the valid rows for queries but that would be a very uncommon implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You try to select data inside row level trigger from the same table at witch inserting this trigger is raised. That's why you got such error.

You don't need additional insert in the trigger on the same table. Just insert
certain rows witch fits your condition.

But if you are going to make much inserting in a future you can do next:

1. Create view as `select * from yourTable`
2. Create trigger `instead of insert on yourView`
3. Add conditional inserting in yourTable in this trigger
4. Make inserting in this view instead of table